# Bounding box not working well in trigger postgresql - postgis

Tags: postgresql, triggers, postgis

My Trigger function consists of collecting the vertices of a polyline table "depart_bt", searching for the point entities of the table “support_bt” which coincide with the vertices of the depart_bt table, then retrieving the value of the "code_dep" attribute (unique identifier of the depart_bt table) of each entity found and report it in the "code_dep" attribute (foreign key in the support_bt table).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION vertex_troncon() RETURNS TRIGGER 
language plpgsql AS 
$$
DECLARE
    box_pt geometry(point);
BEGIN
    IF TG_OP = 'INSERT' OR TG_OP = 'UPDATE' THEN
        IF NEW.code_dep IS NOT NULL THEN
            UPDATE support_bt SET code_dep = NEW.code_dep WHERE support_bt.geom_point IN (SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(NEW.geom_line)).geom);      
            RETURN NULL;
        END IF;
    ELSE
        RAISE WARNING 'Other action occurred: %, at %', TG_OP, now();
        RETURN NULL;
    END IF;
END;
$$
;       
            
-- creation du trigger
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS vertex_dep ON depart_bt;
CREATE TRIGGER vertex_dep AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON depart_bt FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE vertex_troncon();
```

My first code works well, but it has the disadvantage of iterating through all points of "support_bt" which may affect the performance of the trigger. So, I added a bounding box to limit the search area. However, I noticed that the bounding box does not work fine and all points in the support_bt table are selected.

```
/*UPDATE support_bt SET code_dep = NEW.code_dep WHERE support_bt.geom_point IN (SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(NEW.geom_line)).geom);*/
            
SELECT geom_point INTO box_pt FROM support_bt WHERE ST_contains((SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_Extent(NEW.geom_line),32632)), support_bt.geom_point);
UPDATE support_bt SET code_dep = NEW.code_dep WHERE box_pt IN (SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(NEW.geom_line)).geom);
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You can use [`st_envelope`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Envelope.html) to get a polygon in the right CRS. Also have a look at the [`&&`](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_overlaps.html) operator as you don't even need to compute the bounding box. That being said, when "all" features are selected, chances are one of the CRS is wrong

Comment: Thank you JGH. I have tried st_envelope but the same result. All my layers are in the same CSR 32632 and my first code is OK. But how to use && ?